# Unity IoC container name and resolution

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

Are these statements equivalent (Am I getting the same object)?

```
unity.Resolve<ITest>();
```

and

```
unity.Resolve<ITest>(name : null);
```

If not what is the default name when I register without passing in the name parameter?

Eg. when I do this:

```
unity.RegisterType<ITest,Test>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are equivalent and you will get the same type. The generic `RegisterType` methods are in fact extension methods, and all of them call the same method on `UnityContainer`.

```
IUnityContainer RegisterType(Type from, Type to, string name, LifetimeManager lifetimeManager, params InjectionMember[] injectionMembers)
```